# Getting 'react-router-dom' error in all the files

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-router, router

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Button.jsx 6:0-40
```

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in 'D:\Agarwal_T\agarwal_traders\src\components'

Can someone please help me.

Comment: how can other people help you without any code or explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try running
npm i react-router react-router-dom --save